# Cannot understand output in the second case

Tags: racket

```
(define c
  (let ((d 10))
    (set! d (- d 2))
    d))
(define c1
  (let ((d 10))
   (lambda (p)
     (set! d (- d p))
     d)))
```

Now for `c c` the output is `8 8`.

But for `(c1 2) (c1 2)` the output is `8 6`. Why is that so?

I think I need an insight to how function calls are actually evaluated.

According to me, the evaluation should be as, (in the second case) for the first call, a local environment for function c1 is created where the value of d is 10 and then the procedure evaluation takes place normally. Then as soon as this call ends the whole environment is destroyed and for the second call the same whole process (as above) occurs. So the second output value should also be 8. But it is 6, why is that so?

Comment: Is `c` a function, or a number? For me evaluating `(c 2)` produces an "application: not a procedure" error.

Comment: Sorry, please see the edits @Alex Knauth

Comment: For the first case `c`, the `set!` expression is evaluated once. For the second case `c1`, the `set!` expression is evaluated multiple times, once for each time the function is called.

Comment: @Alex Knauth I am sure in both cases set! is evaluated 2 times

Comment: It only gets evaluated once when `c` is initialized. From then on, the value of `c` is `8`, and referring to `c` multiple times doesn't re-evaluate that.

Comment: `d` is not part of `c1` local environment. It is binding captured by `lambda` form. And it is not created and destroyed each time procedure called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you thinking this:

```
(define c1
  (let ((d 10))
    (lambda (p)
      (set! d (- d p))
      d)))
```

It is exactly the same as:

```
(define c1
  (lambda (p)
    (let ((d 10))
      (set! d (- d p))
      d)))
```

It is not. In the first the variable `d` is created before the lambda and thus it is the same free variable for each and every invocation of `c1`. Thus changing `d` alters next call.

The second one creates `d` at invocation and it gets destroyed when the call is finished.

In the first Scheme evaluates the let form. It creates `d` and then evaluates the lambda so `d` becomes a free variable in its closure that is returned. The define syntax then creates a global variable `c1` with that resulting closure value. The `let` is out of scope, but `d` doesn't get garbage collected since it is still referenced by one value, the closure.

Answer (score 0):

A `let` can be rewritten as an immediate application of a `lambda` abstraction

```
(mylet ([var rhs] ...) body ...) => ((lambda (var ...) body ...) rhs ...)
```

De-sugaring `c`'s `let` yields

```
(define c ((lambda (d) (set! d (- d 2)) d) 10))
```

Which is just an application of `10` onto a function (which we  call `f`)

```
(define f (lambda (d) (set! d (- d 2)) d))
(define c 
  (f 10))
c
c
```

As for `c1`, we  have nested lambdas

```
(define f1 (lambda (d) (lambda (p) (set! d (- d p)) d)))
((f1 10) 2)
((f1 10) 2)
```

`8` and `8`. **(Which is what you expected).** But really, what's happening is

```
(define c1
  (f1 10))
(c1 2)
(c1 2)
```

returns `8` and `6`

The d gets *memoized* ([here](https://www.scheme.com/tspl4/binding.html#./binding:h7) is an example of fibonacci using the same wrapping of a memoize procedure and `set!`).

Moreover, for `set!`, you can't have naive substitution. The racket's [evaluation model](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._.Procedure_.Applications_and_.Local_.Variables%29) explains how "a new location is created for each variable on each application":

> Since the value associated with argument variable x can be changed,
>   the value cannot be substituted for x when the procedure is first
>   applied.

**tl;dr** evaluation of `c1` yields a lambda that closes over pending substitution (environment). Which is then mutated by `set!` on each call.

Comment: I don't think you should use the term _memoized_ here. It specifically means remembering the results of a function so that you don't have to re-compute them later. Maybe you meant something closer to "closed over" and just used the wrong term.

Comment: Yes, that is true, _memoized_ is not the most accurate term for it in that context. Thanks!